# is it possible make two GET endpoints in djangorestframework via APIVIEW

Tags: django-rest-framework

Me need make two GET endpoint in django rest framework in one classes
this is endpoints will work with another system via api

i tried

```
class MyApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'test':'test'})

    @list_route(methods=['GET'], )
    def two_endpoint(self, request):
        return Response({'test': 'test'})
```

but this not work
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean, two views for the same endpoint (url)? What are you trying to do?

Comment: yes, me need make class in which will such GET routs

http://example.com/api/myapiview/

http://example.com/api/myapiview/two_enpoint/

http://example.com/api/myapiview/three_endpoin/

Answer (score 2):

<strike>try to use [ModelViewset class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset),


**views.py**</strike>

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class MyApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()

    def function_name_1(self, request):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")

    def function_name_2(self, request):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")

    def function_name_3(self, request, pk):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.conf.urls import url
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'myendpoint', MyApiView)

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^myendpoint/end_point_1/$', MyApiView.as_view({'get': 'function_name_1'}), name='function_name_1'),
url(r'^myendpoint/end_point_2/$', MyApiView.as_view({'post': 'function_name_2'}), name='function_name_2'),
url(r'^myendpoint/end_point_3/$', MyApiView.as_view({'put': 'function_name_3'}), name='function_name_3'),
              ]+router.urls
```

**UPDATE-1**
Change your `views.py` to this,

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class MyApiView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def function_name_1(self, request):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")

    def function_name_2(self, request):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")

    def function_name_3(self, request):
        # do stuff
        return Response(data="return your data")
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer, but i not will use my models in this class,
so I cannot use the modelviewset

Comment: I updated the answer, try it and let me know if it works

Comment: thank you, this working, but i decided to use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781497/7890051